# How to better use and interpret granger test in R?

Tags: r, time-series, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, granger-causality

I have the following code and I want to show the connection of two different factors with a specific one. I want to use `grangertest` in R and I have the following question:

1. how can I interpret the results based on different levels of significance?
2. how can I interpret non-significant results?
3. is there a way to visualise the results?

R code:

````r
my_example <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 10))
my_example$X1 <- c(0.8619616, 1.1818621, 0.5530410, 0.6255634, 
       0.9971764, 1.3464298, 2.0889985, 1.5303893, 2.9503790, 
       2.9244321)
my_example$X2 <- c( -5.7333332, -4.7000000, -7.7000000, 
     -2.5000000,  1.5666667,  0.2666667, -2.7000000, -6.2000000, 
      0.2333333  ,0.5333333)
my_example$X3 <- c( 0.2200000, 0.3625000, 0.2100000, 0.3750000, 
      0.4966667, 0.4133333, 0.3800000, 0.2133333, 0.3733333, 
      0.4400000)

grangertest(X1 ~ X2, order = 2, data = my_example)

grangertest(X1 ~ X3, order = 2, data = my_example)
```
````

Answer (score 2):

The test performed in grangertest is to compare a model with (lagged versions of) X3 and X1 against a model with just X1. This model comparison is performed using a Wald test, which may aid you in finding details about the comparison.

The null hypothesis is that the "full model" including X3 or X2 as well as X1 is not any more predictive than a model predicting X1 using just (lagged) X1.

1. Differing levels of significance represent levels of confidence in your rejection of the null, just as they would with any other statistical test.
2. Non-significant results mean, as it would with any other statistical test, that you cannot reject the null. That is, there is not sufficient evidence in the data to say that the full model is more predictive than the simpler model, nor to be able to suggest that X forecasts Y.
3. I imagine with a larger dataset it might  be useful to plot (lagged) time series beside each other. Something like this:

```r
my_example <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 10))
my_example$X1 <- c(0.8619616, 1.1818621, 0.5530410, 0.6255634, 
       0.9971764, 1.3464298, 2.0889985, 1.5303893, 2.9503790, 
       2.9244321)
my_example$X2 <- c( -5.7333332, -4.7000000, -7.7000000, 
     -2.5000000,  1.5666667,  0.2666667, -2.7000000, -6.2000000, 
      0.2333333  ,0.5333333)
my_example$X3 <- c( 0.2200000, 0.3625000, 0.2100000, 0.3750000, 
      0.4966667, 0.4133333, 0.3800000, 0.2133333, 0.3733333, 
      0.4400000)
par(mfrow=2:1)                                                              
plot(my_example$X1, type="l")                                               
plot(my_example$X2, type="l")
```

[image]